# ¿A qué se debe este error en JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

El error es el siguiente:

> ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error ----- In undefined:1,1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0

Agradezco la ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Comment: Si pones el json que te está dando el error te podremos dar una respuesta mas acercada al problema real

Answer (score 3):

Básicamente significa que tu `JSON` no es un `JSON` pues comienza (posición 0) con un carácter inválido.

Básicamente un `JSON` sólo puede comenzar con cualquiera de 3 opciones:

- Uno de los 25 caracteres whitespace (varios tipos de espacios en blanco)
- `{`
- `[`

Sin más información que la que has dado lo mas probable es que el problema sea uno de los siguientes:

- La cadena JSON, archivo o variable está `vacío`, es `null` o `undefined`. No hay ningun carácter que leer.
- Comienza por ´//´ Algunos parser de JSON podría aceptar comentarios (comúnmente utilizados si se trata de un archivo de configuración) pero la especificación de `JSON` no los considera válidos, por lo que un parser estricto los marcará correctamente como inválido
- Comienza por `"`. Como si todo el `JSON` estuviera delimitado por `""` como si se tratara de un string
- Comienza por `<`. Esperabas un `JSON` pero probablemente tienes un `XML`.

A juzgar por que aparece la palabra `undefined`, no se menciona cual es el caracter inesperado y el error es en la posición 0, definitivamente en este caso la variable donde se encuentra el `JSON` que tratas de parsear es `undefined`, por eso el error.

Asegúrate de estar asignando el valor a esa variable correctamente.

Comment: Pon el json que te esta dando ese error para poder ver mas claramente.